# fix Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf' in ie8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I am getting a script error in ie8 for an array object.
The error is :  "Object doesnt support property or method 'indexOf'

Anyone have an idea or info on how to best solve this for ie8?

Thanks

```
 var arr = new Array();
 Array.prototype.remove = function() {
 var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
 while (L && this.length) {
    what = a[--L];
    while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
        this.splice(ax, 1);
    }
   }
  return this;
};
```

Comment: it is not supported in IE8.. You need to add a pollyfill. Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill

Comment: Take the polyfill implementation from the corresponding MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill

Comment: Unlike most IE error messages, this one pretty much nails it.